# Importing a module in the module

Tags: python, import

```
#file cf.py
a=1      
import cf
print(cf.a)
```

1. Why importing operation in it modules doesn't go in cycles(import module itself)?
2. Why the instruction of print is carried out 2 times in IDLE, and in the console of 1 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first time a module is imported, an entry for it is made in `sys.modules`.  `sys.modules` is a dict, mapping the module name to the module code.  All subsequent imports of the same module find the module's name in `sys.modules`, and simply retrieve the module's code from the `sys.modules` dict.  So the **code** in the module is executed only once, the first time it's imported.  That's why no error results from importing `cf` from within `cf`.
2. You didn't explain **exactly** what you did with IDLE.  My guess:  you had `cf.py` open in an IDLE window, and did "Run Module" (F5) in that window.  Fine.  Then IDLE ran the code in the file.  That's not the same as **importing** `cf`:  it's running the code in `cf` directly.    Part of running that code is importing `cf`, which prints `cf.a`.  Another part of running that code is - again! - printing `cf.a`.  That's why you saw it twice.

By the way, I don't know what you mean by "and in the console 1 times".  But, again, you didn't explain exactly what you did.  When I run `cf.py` from a console, I see `1` two times, and for the same reason I just explained:

```
$ python cf.py
1
1
```

Comment: Thank you. I mistakenly ran the code in the console function import.